# How to visit another host inside docker?

Tags: networking, docker

I have two servers on the same LAN. Their IP addresses are `10.0.0.1 (Server A)` and `10.0.0.2 (Server B)`.

The MySQL server runs on Server B.

The `docker` container runs on Server A. It's IP address is `172.17.0.2`, and the `eth0` of the host is `172.17.0.1`.

My question is, how to connect to Server B in the `docker` container inside Server A?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something very easy to setup is the new Docker swarm mode (if you have Docker 1.12.2) https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/

With this all you have to do is connect your two servers by following the doc. You can then [create an overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/). Then to create your containers you will have to use the command `docker service create` instead of `docker run`.

You may also want to use [some constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#/specify-service-constraints---constraint) to specify where the services should run.